# How do I update the default version of python when using Anaconda

Tags: python, version, conda

I'm trying to start using Python 3.9 and am unable to make this happen.
From the Anaconda Prompt I run and get this:

```
C:\Users\fname lname>python --version
Python 3.7.10
```

I thought I had installed 3.9 already, so I check to see if I have it and I run this command:

```
C:\Users\fname lname>conda search python
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel
python                        2.7.13     h1b6d89f_16  pkgs/main
python                        2.7.13     h9912b81_15  pkgs/main
...
python                         3.9.1      h6244533_2  pkgs/main
python                         3.9.2      h6244533_0  pkgs/main
```

Sure enough it looks like I have 3.9.2 so I run

```
conda install python=3.9.2
```

Here I'm getting a lot of conflict errors and I'm not sure really what actually is happening if anything.
It's a pretty long list of items that pop up and most of it scrolls long enough that I can't recover all of the lines:

```
...
Package hdf5 conflicts for:
hdf5
opencv -> hdf5[version='>=1.10.2,<1.10.3.0a0|>=1.10.4,<1.10.5.0a0|>=1.8.20,<1.9.0a0|>=1.8.18,<1.8.19.0a0']

Package pkginfo conflicts for:
conda-build -> pkginfo
pkginfo

Package pywin32-ctypes conflicts for:
keyring -> pywin32-ctypes[version='!=0.1.0,!=0.1.1']
pywin32-ctypes
spyder -> keyring[version='>=17.0.0'] -> pywin32-ctypes[version='!=0.1.0,!=0.1.1']
```

And running the same version command as before I get Python 3.7.10

Comment: Look up "Windows add to path". You want to add the folder containing python 3.9 and remove the folder containing 3.7 from the path.

Comment: @Kraigolas so I found a version of python.exe that when opened launches the command prompt and shows that Python 3.9.2 is running, it's in this folder: C:\Users\fname lname\Anaconda3\pkgs\python-3.9.2-h6244533_0 but wouldn't it be better to have the python.exe in the ...Anaconda3\ folder just point to the 3.9.2 version?